# How can I pass flags and parameters to mgconsole when I use Memgraph Platform?

Tags: memgraphdb

When I use `mgconsole` on my OS (Linux, Unbutnu 22) I run it with `mgconsole --host 127.0.0.1 --port 7687 --username ttinker --password riegd8cb57`.

Now I'm trying out Memgrpah Platform docker image. When I start it using `run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 memgraph/memgraph-platform` I can see the mgconsole already up, but I can't pass username and password to it. Can I somehow pass that info to Memgraph Platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Memgraph Platform you need to pass flags to `mgconsole` when you are starting your Docker. Your command should be:

```
docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 -e MGCONSOLE="--username ttinker --password riegd8cb57" memgraph/memgraph-platform
```