# How can I check which mgconsole flags are used and what are their values?

Tags: memgraphdb

I've read the questions related to setting the values of `mgconsole` ([How can I pass flags and parameters to mgconsole when I use Memgraph Platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76117314/how-can-i-pass-flags-and-parameters-to-mgconsole-when-i-use-memgraph-platform) and [Can I change the output format for SHOW CONFIG when using mgconsole?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76323497/can-i-change-the-output-format-for-show-config-when-using-mgconsole)) and I've read the docs at https://memgraph.com/docs/getting-started/cli#configure-mgconsole.

I can not find how do show which config flags are used and what are their values in the instance that I'm running at the moment.

What would be equivalent to `SHOW CONFIG` query?